# Address Operator (ampersand) & with @media query is not working

Tags: css, sass, css-selectors, less, scss-mixins

I am sharing the code snippet below in which i am using nesting but I am confused how to use media query inside it.

```
. connection {

   @media only screen and (max-width: 1200px) {

       & > .list {

           grid-template-columns: 1fr;
       }
   }
}
```

Comment: I don't think you can nest media queries, they still need to be at the root. Just like `@import` statements and the like. Anything with an `@`, really. So you need to inverse your logic here a bit.

Answer (score 0):

From [@media](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@media):

> The `@media` at-rule may be placed at the top level of your code or nested inside any other [conditional group at-rule](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/At-rule#conditional_group_rules).

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 1200px) {
  .connection {
    & > .list {
      grid-template-columns: 1fr;
    }
  }
}
```